# Should I allow my custom iterator to go past the end?

Tags: c++, iterator, idioms

I'm implementing an iterator for a class which is based on an index. There's a maximum valid value; my question is about what to do when client code advances the iterator beyond my `end()` value:

- Should `operator++()` always check I don't get past the end?, or
- Should `operator*()` always check I'm not past the end, while the iterator can be (uselessly) advanced or moved past the end?

Please address a non-debug setting in which I can't be certain that silly developers won't try to advance their pointers past the end.

Comment: Generally, it would be a good idea to at least do checks in debug version. And both function should have validation since you cannot dereference an iterator at end.

Comment: I'd `assert()` those checks.

Comment: @Phil1970: Ok, but see edit.

Comment: @melpomene: Ok, but see edit.

Comment: Just been trolling around source code and all implementations I have seen do neither. Basically, once you increment past the end, all bets are off. Although I agree with the other comments - I would be inclined to assert in debug builds.

Comment: @einpoklum My comment stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.

To conform to STL conventions, you need a begin() method which returns an iterator to the start of the collection, and an end() method which returns an iterator to one past the last element. So advancing to end() and comparing for equality is well-defined. However advancing beyond end() is not well-defined. It's better to throw an error, but not necessary, especially if that involves otherwise redundant checks. If people don't use the iterators correctly, you are not responsible for any bugs.

Comment: The fact that it isn't well-defined does not necessarily mean it _should_ be undefined for a specific iterator. Or - are you suggesting that I should let client code shoot itself in the foot if it advances past the end? That's a valid option I suppose.

Comment: @einpoklum - Undefined behavior is just another phrasing for having a narrow API contract. By only agreeing to a narrow contract ("use incorrectly at own risk"), you can supply code that isn't bogged by redundant checks. Iterators are so common a pattern, as well as their use in the C++ standard library, that I honestly don't see the risk of anyone using your iterator incorrectly as being too probable.

Comment: @einpoklum - Also, a narrow contract can always be broadened. Not so much the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add stringent checking code when compiling debugging versions and remove those checks for the release version of the code.

I use `assert` (or similar) extensively. It performs runtime checks *unless* you compile with the macro `NDBUG` defined, in which case the checks are completely eliminated.

The STL philosophy itself should provide a measure of safety being that the iterator limits generally come from a safe place.

When you run an *algorithm* you usually get your bounds from a container like this:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};

do_some_stuff(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

Otherwise you may get your iterator as the result of an algorithm:

```
auto found_iter = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

This makes using iterators pretty safe. It gets a little dangerous when you start using iterator athematic:

```
auto dangerous_iter = std::begin(v) + 5; // not encouraged
```

But errors should be caught during the debugging phase using `assert` and similar.

Another point to remember is if you make your iterator "safe" by run-time checks you can end up **hiding errors** in your code. Because of that such runtime checks should cause a visible spectacle like an exception, don't just silently do nothing.

Answer (score -2):

#### Yes, and don't bother with range checks *anywhere*.

Based on @MalcolmMclean's answer: Since the C++ standard doesn't define the behavior of iterators when moved past the end of a range, it's the client code's problem to make sure it doesn't do that - not yours. So when you're not debugging, don't bother sacrificing performance for range checks, just assume you're not going past the end.

When you *are* compiling for debugging, then as @Phil1970 suggests, range checks with exception-throwing or using assertions may be a good idea.